# Best Practices in Handling Modules Prerequisites

Tags: python, installation, package, distribution, easy-install

Recently I started working on a personal project in my notebook that, all going OK, it will be placed in a server elsewhere. The problem is that I make use of modules. Some were installed from apt-get, others from easy_install and one or two of those were placed directly under a subdirectory since I changed them a bit. My question is: is there a way to move all those things together? Moreover, I don't want any of those modules being updated since it may break something. How to handle that?

Finally, I'm pretty sure that I've done things the wrong way since the beginning. How do you guys work to avoid those problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). Virtualenv is a tool to create isolated Python environments.